# Swift - How to play URLSession before finalizing a function?

Tags: ios, swift

I am currently using a URLSession to send and receive data from a web server, but I have the problem that the query is executed at the end of any other code that follows it, for example if I have the following instructions:

```
_ = URLSession.shared.dataTask (with: url_request) 
{(data, response, error) in
}.resume ()

print ("Hello world")
```

First you will run the "Hello world" and then the http query, how can I make the URLSession run and then what is left of the code?

Comment: Just put the code dependent upon the completion of the request _inside_ the completion handler closure instead of after it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution I found:

```
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

_ = URLSession.shared.dataTask (with: url_request) 
{(data, response, error) in
   print("One")
   semaphore.signal()
}.resume ()

_ = semaphore.wait(timeout: DispatchTime.distantFuture)
print (“Two”)
```

And this is what prints:

```
>> One
>> Two
```

Comment: This blocks the thread onto which you are executing the semaphore which in most cases would probably end up being the main thread.  Blocking the main thread is a huge deal and should be avoided at all costs. A URL request can take quite a long time to fulfill depending on the network, upwards of 30 seconds.  If your main thread blocks for 30 seconds, the user will believe the app is crashed and probably kill it, if iOS doesn't do it automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

URL sessions are asynchronous and involve time in communicating back and forth to a server.  You have to use a variant of the URLSession that allows you to have a completion handler:

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: my_url) { (response_data, url_response, communication_error) in
        print ("Hello World")
    }
```

Good luck!